# How to load 2 tableViews on one MasterViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do I load 2 tableViews on my MasterViewController? The code of the tableView-method I have is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        }

        SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;


    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    if ([[FlamencompasIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    } else {
        UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
        [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
    }
    }
    //UITableView *tableView2;
    if(tableView == self.tableView2)
    //else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        }

        SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products2[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;


        [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

        if ([[FlamencompasIAPHelper sharedInstance2] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
        } else {
            UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
            [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
            [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

the code after `if(tableView == self.tableView2)` is not executed. How to 'declare' tableView2?
I am only able to either load the first or the second tableView. But I want to load them both. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your method should look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        // All code related to self.tableView
    } else if (tableview == self.tableView2) {
        // All code related to self.tableView2
    } else {
        return nil; // oops
    }
}
```

Also make sure `self.tableView` and `self.tableView2` are set properly. Perhaps `self.tableView2` is `nil`.

Comment: But where and how do I have to load tableView2 then?

Comment: The same way you load `self.tableView`. You have a `UIViewController` with two table views added referenced by your `tableView` and `tableView2` properties, right? Call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to reload `tableView` and call `[self.tableView2 reloadData]` to reload `tableView2`.

Comment: My MasterViewController.h looks like:

Comment: @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
{

}

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

Comment: Is this what you mean by UIViewController with 2 table views?

Comment: You should not add a second table view to a `UITableViewController`. If you want two table view in one view controller, use a `UIViewController` and add two table views to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 tableview data source classes to avoid making your master view controller a very long and difficult to understand class. If you implement the UITableViewDataSource methods in the same class (i.e. MasterViewController) you will end up with multiple if/else statements everywhere which are hard to maintain and refactor.

This explains in more detail how you can separate you data source from you view controller http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html